# How can I inject an implementation of EJB 3 if I only know which one to use until runtime based on a condition?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

Is there a way to decide what EJB implementation to use at runtime when you have more than one implementation? I can't use annotations or deployment descriptor because the logic is not known until runtime.

Let's say that I have the following EJBs implementations:
`MyEJBFoo` `MyEJBBar`, both implement `MyEJB` business interface. How can I still do dependency injection of that EJB if the implementation to use is known until runtime with let's say a flag called `DEV_MODE` = TRUE/FALSE stored in a resource bundle and if it is true it must use `MyEJBFoo` and if it is false then `MyEJBBar`.

I was thinking factory pattern but I'm not sure if it is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a delegating `MyEJB`:

```
public class MyEJBDelegatingImpl implements MyEJB {
    // Inject: can't remember exact annotation
    private MyEJB myEJBFoo;

    // Inject: can't remember exact annotation
    private MyEJB myEJBBar;

    private getDelegate() {
        if (condition for myEJBFoo) {
            return myEJBFoo;
        } else {
            return myEJBBar;
        }
    }

    ...
    //Now implement MyEJB delegating to getDelegate()
}
```

Only caveat is that both instances (myEJBFoo and myEJBBar) have to be instantiable no matter what the environment conditions are, because you are injecting both unconditionally in the delegating `MyEJB`.

Comment: How do you know, that in the myEJBFoo will have that correct implementation (MyEJBFoo) and not MyEJBBar, after injection?

Comment: The annotation that miss are @EJB(beanName="MyEJBFoo") and @EJB(beanName="MyEJBBar")

Answer (score 2):

Just be aware of the resolving the injection points accordingly, when using one interface for two implementations (described [here](http://roland-tiefenbrunner.blogspot.com/2012/01/ejb-3x-one-interface-two.html)).

Furthermore, if you have the possibility to use CDI, check out the [producer methods](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/producermethods.html), as they make exactly such things possible.